Standard Airliner Roll Rates Under Autopilot Control?
Do Boeing-Airbus planes under autopilot control adhere to standardized roll rates during routine maneuvers?
For Example: A 5 degrees per second roll rate between 0 and 20 degrees of bank?

On a 737, the roll rate is greater when rolling from level flight to a 30 degree bank than when rolling to a lesser bank angle.  The bank angle to be used in HDG mode is selectable between 10 and 30 degrees, in 5-degree increments.  In other modes such as LNAV and Localizer, the AFDS decides for itself how much bank it will use, as well as how quickly it will roll into that bank.  Capturing a localizer, for instance, tends to be pretty aggressive if the intercept angle is high; if the angle is shallow, the bank and roll rates tend to be much less.
I have to imagine that this, along with pretty well everything else, is specified somewhere in some Boeing document, but I don't recall ever seeing those numbers published in pilot manuals.
